# To simplify your public-facing API, can you make your platform-specific type aliases private if they alias already-public types?

Tags: swift, uikit, appkit, multiplatform, type-alias

The title may seem a little confusing, but consider this scenario.  We have the following extensions on `UIView` for iOS/iPadOS apps.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {

    var isVisible:Bool{
        get{ return !isHidden }
        set{ isHidden = !newValue }
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews:UIView...) {
        addSubviews(subviews)
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews:[UIView]) {
        subviews.forEach{ addSubview($0) }
    }
}
```

We have the exact same extensions on `NSView` for macOS apps.

```
import AppKit

extension NSView {

    var isVisible:Bool{
        get{ return !isHidden }
        set{ isHidden = !newValue }
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews: NSView...) {
        addSubviews(subviews)
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews: [NSView]) {
        subviews.forEach{ addSubview($0) }
    }
}
```

The only difference between the two is one uses `UIView`, the other uses `NSView`.

To get rid of that redundancy, and to eliminate having to add the platform checks everywhere, we simply aliased the class names themselves, then built the APIs around those aliases, like so...

```
#if os(iOS) || os(tvOS)
    import UIKit
    typealias PlatformView = UIView
#elseif os(OSX)
    import AppKit
    typealias PlatformView = NSView
#endif

extension PlatformView {

    var isVisible:Bool{
        get{ return !isHidden }
        set{ isHidden = !newValue }
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews: PlatformView...) {
        addSubviews(subviews)
    }

    func addSubviews(_ subviews:[PlatformView]) {
        subviews.forEach{ addSubview($0) }
    }
```

The issue is we now have to expose `PlatformView` publicly, which may confuse those importing our Swift package.  We're hoping they would just see either `UIView` or `NSView` depending on their platform.

So... is that possible to hide your type aliases and instead expose the public types they alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you expect is the behaviour of preprocecessor macros. Typealiases are replaced to their underlying types at compile time, which makes them identical to the types they alias.

However, the interfaces using a type alias will still expose the type alias instead of the underlying type, since one of the main use cases of type aliases is to provide a more meaningful (at least in some context) name to other types or to combine several types (like `typealias ABProtocol = AProtocol & BProtocol`) into a single name, so the interfaces not exposing said type aliases would take away one of the main use cases of `typealias`es.

As I've stated in the beginning of my answer, you would to use preprocessor macros to replace your type alias with the represented type *before* compilation time and hence to expose the aliased type in your public interface.

However, sadly in Swift preprocessor macros aren't as powerful as in Obj-C. You cannot replace type names in preprocessor macros and cannot place type declarations/the opening of an extension in a preprocessor macro.

So there is no way to achieve your goal of avoiding both code duplication and having to expose a type alias in your public interface.

Comment: Yes, they do that *at compile time* but as I said, to the developer who is including my package, they don't see the compiled code.  They see an API exposing the type alias, which they will go see that it's just an alias to the type they're already working with. I know this because I myself see similar things in others' APIs and I'm always wondering why they are using type aliases instead of the actual types.  Now that I've hit this, I know why, but it still seems unneeded if the type is public but the alias is private. It's an alias, which means it's an exact stand-in, not an 'is a' relation.

Comment: @MarkA.Donohoe as I've explained in my answer, _"It's an alias, which means it's an exact stand-in, not an 'is a' relation."_ is not true. Please re-read the 2nd paragraph for why that is the case. I understand your frustration about not being able to achieve your goals, since ideally they should be achievable with preprocessor macros. However, at the current point in time, Swift is simply not capable of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'd argue it *is* still an exact stand-in, even in your example of the combined type.  Anywhere that takes a combined type can take something defined with that type alias, *and vice-versa* (that's the important bit over say, subclassing.)  That's what the word 'alias' means! BUT... I get what you mean about why the aliases are exposed instead of the underlying type.  It's just frustrating that has to be the case. Either that or I have to put the conditional compilation checks everywhere, at least for the publicly-facing members. I can still happily use the typealiases internally.